# wshShell.SendKeys(Chr(&hAF)) doesn't work

Tags: hotkeys, sendkeys, chr

The `wshShell.SendKeys(Chr(&hAF))` which should turn up the volume doens't work.

The other 2 commands  `(sendkeys for Chr(&hAE) and Chr(&hAD))` works perfect.

But these commands are useless if you can't turn the volume up but only turn it down.

I have other win7 system where all 3 commands work just fine.

How can the win7 mess like that?! And what should i do to make the volume up hot key work?

Comment: Well, i just figured that if i compile the script it works fine. So this command doesn't work only if i run .vbs file.

Comment: Structure the text makes it more readable for others.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
WshShell.SendKeys("¯")
```

or

```
WshShell.SendKeys(chr(175))
```